# Dropzone specify file id

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I wonder if it is possible to specify a file id. For instance, if you have an element:

```
<input type='text id='1'>
```

When this field is submitted within a form, the form data is serialized as `1=blah`.

When I use dropzone, my first file is id as `file[0]`. Is there a way to assign it a proper name?

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Can you explain with a bit more detail, or show a clear example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @wallek876 When a form is submitted, each input field is submitted in the form of `id=value`. When the files inside dropzone is submitted, it is in the format of `file[0]=value`. I wanted to give it an id instead of the default name of `file[0]`

Comment: You can change the array name, lets say from `file[]` to `myupload[]`, but will always be `myupload[]` then, I don't think you can change the structure itself of the resulting array. Not sure what is your goal. The name of the file should be in `file[]["name"]`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I want to associate an id with the fileupload so that I would know which files belong to which dropzone component. (I may have more than one dropzone component on the page)

Comment: If what you want is to differentiate which dropzone uploads the file, you have serveral options, one would be to use a different file for each dropzone element that handles the upload, other can be to push additional information with the upload, this could look like `formId => 1`, and then do according to the `formId` different things.